# GET Method failing on Node.js Express backend application

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing

I am trying to create a backend application using Node.js and Express to get post and modify user data from a .json file. Here is my app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

//setting up the express router
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//write the code for routes here
app.post("/add", function(req, resp){

 var jsonObject = req.body;
 var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF8");
 var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
 jsonArray.push(jsonObject);

 jsonFile = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
 resp.json(jsonFile);
 fs.writeFileSync("get.json",jsonFile,"utf-8");

});
app.get('/view/:id?', function(req, resp){
  var queryURL = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF8");
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  var id = req.params.id;
  // if(typeof queryURL.id === "undefined" || queryURL.id == 0){
  //   resp.json(data);
  // }else{
  //   resp.json(data[queryURL.id-1]);
  // }
  if (id >= 0) {
    data.array.every(user => {
        if (user.id === id) {  
            resp.json(user);
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log("Next")
        }
    });
  } else{
    resp.json(data);
  }

});

app.patch("/edit/:id", function(req, res){
    let userID = req.params.id;
    let userFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF-8");
    let userArray = JSON.parse(userFile);
    
    let reqUserObject = req.body;

    let newUserArray = userArray.map(user => {
        if (user.id === userID) {
            updatedUser = {...user, ...reqUserObject};
            return updatedUser;
        } else {
            return user;
        }
    });
    
    userFileData = JSON.stringify(newUserArray);
    res.json(userFileData);
    fs.writeFileSync("get.json", userFileData, "UTF-8");
});
module.exports = app;
```

All methods work except for

> app.get('/view/:id?', function(req, resp)

This Method has an optional query parameter id, if you pass an id you get a user with an id equal to that id. If you dont pass in an id, you get all the users from get.json.

The json file (get.json) I used is:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"updated name","age":"22","gender":"Male","email":"userone@gmail.com"},{"id":"2","name":"user two","age":"24","gender":"Female","email":"usertwo@gmail.com"},{"id":"3","name":"user three","age":"23","gender":"Male","email":"userthree@gmail.com"},{"id":"4","name":"user four","age":"21","gender":"Male","email":"userfour@gmail.com"}]
```

And my test file is:

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app");
const md5 = require("md5");
const fs = require("fs");

//updating a user profile
test("Updating a user", async () => {
  await request(app)
    .patch("/edit/1")
    .send({
      name: "updated name",
    })
    .expect(200);
  setTimeout(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../post.json"));
    expect(data.length).toBe(5);
    expect(data[0].name).toBe("updated name");
  }, 1000);
});

// // posting a data
test("Posting a new data", async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post("/add")
    .send({
      id: "5",
      name: "user new",
      age: "36",
      gender: "Female",
      email: "usernew@gmail.com",
    })
    .expect(200);
  setTimeout(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../post.json"));
    expect(data.length).toBe(5);
  }, 1000);
});

//checking the get route
test("Getting all the user data", async () => {
  const response = await request(app).get("/view").expect(200);
  expect(response.body.length).toBe(4);
  expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("f1d3ff8443297732862df21dc4e57262");
});

//getting profile of a user based on id
test("Getting a single user data", async () => {
  const response = await request(app).get("/view?id=2").expect(200);
  expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
  expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("93b885adfe0da089cdf634904fd59f71");
});
```

When I run the tests I get:

> rm -rf ./test-report.xml && CI=true ./node_modules/.bin/jest
> --testResultsProcessor ./node_modules/jest-junit-reporter --forceExit; t-reporter --forceExit;.bin/jest --testResultsProcessor
> ./node_modules/jest-juni  FAIL test/app.test.js   ✓ Updating a user
> (45ms)   ✓ Posting a new data (17ms)   ✕ Getting all the user data
> (10ms)   ✕ Getting a single user data (4ms)
>
> ● Getting all the user data
>
> ```
> expected 200 "OK", got 500 "Internal Server Error"
>
>   39 | //checking the get route
>   40 | test("Getting all the user data", async () => {
> > 41 |   const response = await request(app).get("/view").expect(200);
>      |                                                    ^
>   42 |   expect(response.body.length).toBe(4);
>   43 |   expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("f1d3ff8443297732862df21dc4e57262");
>   44 | });
>
>   at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/app.test.js:41:52)
>   ----
>   at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
>   at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:306:17
>   at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
>   at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
>   at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
> ```
>
> ● Getting a single user data
>
> ```
> expected 200 "OK", got 500 "Internal Server Error"
>
>   46 | //getting profile of a user based on id
>   47 | test("Getting a single user data", async () => {
> > 48 |   const response = await request(app).get("/view?id=2").expect(200);
>      |                                                         ^
>   49 |   expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
>   50 |   expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("93b885adfe0da089cdf634904fd59f71");
>   51 | });
>
>   at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/app.test.js:48:57)
>   ----
>   at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
>   at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:306:17
>   at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
>   at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
>   at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       2 failed, 2 passed, 4
> total Snapshots:   0 total Time:        1.612s Ran all test suites.
> Force exiting Jest: Have you considered using `--detectOpenHandles` to
> detect async operations that kept running after all tests finished?

We can see the last 2 tests ("Getting all the user data" and "Getting a single user data") did not pass. These 2 test the app.get('/view/:id?', function(req, resp) method.

How could I fix my app.get('/view/:id?', function(req, resp) method?

**Update:**

I fixed my app.js according to the suggestion of Yago Biermann, but it is still unable to pass the last 2 tests. My revised app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

//setting up the express router
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//write the code for routes here
app.post("/add", function(req, resp){

 var jsonObject = req.body;
 var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF8");
 var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
 jsonArray.push(jsonObject);

 jsonFile = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
 resp.json(jsonFile);
 fs.writeFileSync("get.json",jsonFile,"utf-8");

});
app.get('/view', function(req, resp) {
  
  const id = req.query.id;
  var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF8");
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  // return the whole data if query parameter wasn't provided
  if (!id) return resp.status(200).json(data)

  // you should use find instead of every to get the user data
  const user = data.find(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      return user;
    };
      return null;
  });
  // return the user otherwise return a 404 response
  return user ? resp.status(200).json(user) : resp.status(404).json({message:"user not found"})
});

app.patch("/edit/:id", function(req, res){
    let userID = req.params.id;
    let userFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF-8");
    let userArray = JSON.parse(userFile);
    
    let reqUserObject = req.body;

    let newUserArray = userArray.map(user => {
        if (user.id === userID) {
            updatedUser = {...user, ...reqUserObject};
            return updatedUser;
        } else {
            return user;
        }
    });
    
    userFileData = JSON.stringify(newUserArray);
    res.json(userFileData);
    fs.writeFileSync("get.json", userFileData, "UTF-8");
});
module.exports = app;
```

And what I get when I run the tests:

> rter --forceExit;es/.bin/jest --testResultsProcessor
> ./node_modules/jest-junit-repo  FAIL test/app.test.js   ✓ Updating a
> user (43ms)   ✓ Posting a new data (15ms)   ✕ Getting all the user
> data (9ms)   ✕ Getting a single user data (4ms)
>
> ● Getting all the user data
>
> ```
> expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
>
> Expected: 4
> Received: 5
>
>   40 | test("Getting all the user data", async () => {
>   41 |   const response = await request(app).get("/view").expect(200);
> > 42 |   expect(response.body.length).toBe(4);
>      |                                ^
>   43 |   expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("f1d3ff8443297732862df21dc4e57262");
>   44 | });
>   45 |
>
>   at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/app.test.js:42:32)
> ```
>
> ● Getting a single user data
>
> ```
> expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
>
> Expected: 1
> Received: undefined
>
>   47 | test("Getting a single user data", async () => {
>   48 |   const response = await request(app).get("/view?id=2").expect(200);
> > 49 |   expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
>      |                                ^
>   50 |   expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("93b885adfe0da089cdf634904fd59f71");
>   51 | });
>   52 |
>
>   at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/app.test.js:49:32)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       2 failed, 2 passed, 4
> total Snapshots:   0 total Time:        1.71s Ran all test suites.
> Force exiting Jest: Have you considered using `--detectOpenHandles` to
> detect async operations that kept running after all tests finished?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be at your tests, in your test `"Getting all the user data"` you are making a request to `/view` but you don't have any route to view, at least it's not in your question, note that `/view/:id` is not the same as `/view`. Lastly, in your test `"Getting a single user data"` you are not providing the id for the user as a **url parameter**, instead you are passing it as a **query parameter**, so try to do the following:

```
test("Getting a single user data", async () => {
  // pass the id as url
  const response = await request(app).get("/view/2").expect(200);
  expect(response.params.id).toBe(2);
  expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
  expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("93b885adfe0da089cdf634904fd59f71");
});
```

See the docs about [req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.params). Hope I helped a bit!

**Edit:** As you said that the test file can't be changed, do the following in your `view` route:

```
// Change to view, now the test on route /view should work
app.get('/view', function(req, resp) {
  
  const id = req.query.id;
  var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("get.json", "UTF8");
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  // return the whole data if query parameter wasn't provided
  if (!id) return resp.status(200).json(data)

  // you should use find instead of every to get the user data
  const user = data.find(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      return user;
    };
      return null;
  });
  // return the user otherwise return a 404 response
  return user ? resp.status(200).json([user]) : resp.status(404).json({message:"user not found"})
});
```

Comment: My circumstances dictate that I could not change the test file. Any changes I make must be done in app.js

Comment: So you must make it clear in your question, anyway, I updated the answer.

Comment: I applied this change, but it still is not work. See my updated edits above.

Comment: Your test **"getting single user data"** is expecting to get an array of user, try to send the user within an array, like so: `return user ? resp.status(200).json([user]) : resp.status(404).json({message:"user not found"})` , I changed the answer again, take a look.

Comment: I tried again with your latest answer, and was able to pass the "Getting a single user data" test. However, I was not able to pass the "Getting all the user data". Instead I get this message:

Comment: ● Getting all the user data

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 4
    Received: 5

      40 | test("Getting all the user data", async () => {
      41 |   const response = await request(app).get("/view").expect(200);
    > 42 |   expect(response.body.length).toBe(4);
         |                                ^
      43 |   expect(md5(response.body)).toBe("f1d3ff8443297732862df21dc4e57262");
      44 | });
      45 |

      at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/app.test.js:42:32)

Comment: The message is very clear, the test expected the response object to have four elements but got **five**, this is happening because you are adding new elements in the file on previous test **"Posting a new data"**, so to fix it you should use another file for the api **"/add"**. I notice that before you were using a file **post.json** and now you changed it to **get.json**, try to let it as it was before, also keep in mind that after running the test the file will have more objects, as you can't modify the tests you must remove the objects manually after the test or create a script to do so.